# Problem when importing .obj to Blender

Tags: mesh, objects, import

just a heads up im relatively new to Blender and in this case Sculptris. I wanted to make a simple first Model and i exported it from Sculptris and imported the wavefront(.obj) file into Blender and it came out like this: 
[image: symmetrieline issue]

As you can see, I added two models. These are basically the same but I followed the recommendation of another post about the same issue I found and reduced the Models Poly Count and tried to import that, I also tried to import the .obj File while "Keeping the Vert Order" but none of that worked.
Here is the referenced stackexchange post : [.OBJ Import Error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38240/obj-import-error/38241?newreg=fd88d415e596427399a9f1f331f317a5)

So I wanted to ask you if anyone has a solution to this Problem and could help me out?
[image: Sculptris Horse]
I want it to look like this, is there any way to have it displayed correctly in Blender?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: On the semmytrie line the texture is so weird. Is there a adjustment i can make to have just the model on both sides rendered normally?

Comment: That looks like a normal issue, have you tried recalculating normals with Ctrl + N after removing doubles with W > Remove doubles?

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion, I went into edit mode Removed Doubles and recalculated normals but sadly that didnt change anything. Do you have any other idea what i could do?

Comment: Could you post your obj file for download somewhere so we can look at it? Hard to tell without any more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *Custom Split Normals* creating artifacts in your mesh.

Go to *Properties Window > Object Data Tab > Geometry Data Panel* and press *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*

If for some reason you wish to keep those, disabling *Auto Smooth* under the *Properties Window > Object Data Tab > Normals Panel > Auto Smooth* seems to be a valid workaround.

Also, if you horse is to remain perfectly symmetric consider erasing half of the mesh and adding a *Mirror* modifier. Might save you some cleanup work and resources in the future.

[image: Horsey Mchorseface]

Comment: Alright thanks, that was what I was looking for. Maybe I should reinstall sculptris if there was a problem with the exported object because this is just an example I had this problem previously too. Might I ask if the mirror modifier safes ressources in general and why it would save me work?

Comment: Updated my answer above, issue seems to be caused by custom split normals. Mirror modifier saves resources in the sense that only half the mesh data needs to be saved in the file/loaded into memory, since the other half is actually identical. It may also save you some work while cleaning up, unwrapping, texturing, or in general doing any modeling or manual work since you would only need to do half of it, instead of doing it twice for each half of the mesh. That is if it actually *is* symmetrical, otherwise never mind that.

Comment: To your Edit: Ah I see it this type of Problem should be solved in sculptris I guess? Either way thanks that was very helpful, now I know what to look out for when something like this happens. Because when i toggle the clear/add custom split Normals Data it is okay in either case ^^

Comment: Never really used Sculptris myself, so not sure if it is actually solvable through the application or not. May be a small incompatibility between the two applications, I don't really know.