# Ambient Occlusion Bake Texture Issue

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, mirror

I have recently updated to Blender 2.8. Now, when I bake an ambient occlusion map of this model it looks like this:

[image: Front View]
[image: Rear View]

This is odd, as it worked fine with two of my other models in 2.8.
I use Smart UV Project for unwrapping, I've got an unapplied Mirror modifier, and I've tried using Merge by Distance, it did nothing.
Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133816/bad-shading-on-imported-mesh/133819#133819  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57006/problem-when-importing-obj-to-blender/57022#57022

Comment: I've found out what the problem was. I had accidentally put the texture that I was baking to in the Subsurface Color slot instead of the Base Color slot. Changing them to the Base Color slot fixed the issue.