# Wierd rendering of a model

Tags: modeling, shaders

I am quite new at blender and I am modeling an airplane. Somewhere along modeling, some strange things occurred. Probably I clicked something or miss-typed a shortcut or something and my model is shaded strange.

I have applied material to this object with default settings.

[image: Strange shading of a model]

[image: Mesh]

I am using blender 3.1. I used quads almost exclusively.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: hello could you please pack your image (if you use an Image Texture, go into File > External Data > Pack Resources and save) and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133816/bad-shading-on-imported-mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57006/problem-when-importing-obj-to-blender